# SBJSon dont like [ ] chars in Json string

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, sbjson

I noticed SBJson failed to decode this json string:

```
[{"JNAME":"VERSION","DATE": "20111012","TIME": "145020"}]
```

If I remove the [ ] the string is successuffly decoded and return a NSDictionnary

my code:

not working (return nil):

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dict   = [ parser objectWithString:result error:&error ];
```

working:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];

NSInteger len        = [result length];

NSError *error = nil

NSString *result2    = [result substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, len - 2 )  ];


NSDictionary *dict   = [ parser objectWithString:result error:&error ];
```

Any ideas why? it s strange because if I use online parser or others Json decode functions (ex : with PHP) the string is successfully decoded :

```
php > $json = '[{"JNAME":"VERSION","DATE": "20111012","TIME": "145020"}]';
php > print_r(json_decode($json));
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
     (
         [JNAME] => VERSION
         [DATE] => 20111012
         [TIME] => 145020
     )

 )
```

Comment: With "[]" there what happens?  What error do you get?  (You realize, of course, that with the "[]" you'll get an array, not a dictionary.)

Comment: you re right , it works if I cast to NSArray instead of NSDictionary !

Comment: Of course I'm right.  A JSON parser returns whatever type the JSON string is -- could be array, dictionary, or an individual literal int/string/boolean.  In the general case (where you don't know for sure what's in the JSON string) you need to test the type before you assume anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array you should have

```
{"arrayname" : [{"JNAME":"VERSION","DATE": "20111012","TIME": "145020"}]}
```

the NSArray will have 1 NSDictionary element. You can check JSON validity [here](http://jsonlint.com/). Note the parser will give you a dictionary with the array for key @"arrayname".

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention my result var is NSDictonary I gonna edit my post.

Comment: @N-AccessDev -- Your result var may be declared NSDictionary, but the result is NSArray.

Comment: yep, I now use an id and cast it to the right class depending on cases. thx